# Самая быстрая реализация алгоритма Дейкстры на javascript

Tags: javascript, алгоритм, производительность, графы

Дан взвешенный граф.
Необходимо решить 2 задачи: найти из начальной точки длины путей до всех точек и также получить (восстановить) самый короткий (дешевый, оптимальный и т.п.) путь из начальной точки в любую другую.

Логично напрашивается алгоритм Дейкстры.

НО!

Нужно, чтобы реализация работала быстро. 
Для оценки: для 160 вершин и 350 рёбер выполнение за 3 миллисекунды - это медленно.

Я пытался найти реализации этого алгоритма на JavaScript в интернете.
Однако либо они были слишком медленные
[Как например эта](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/finding-the-shortest-path-in-javascript-dijkstras-algorithm-8d16451eea34) 
[или эта](https://hackernoon.com/how-to-implement-dijkstras-algorithm-in-javascript-abdfd1702d04)

Либо некорректно работали, т.е. зацикливались, хотя входные данные были корректны
[например это](https://medium.com/@adriennetjohnson/a-walkthrough-of-dijkstras-algorithm-in-javascript-e94b74192026)

Также прикрепляю сюда пример со ~160 вершинами и ~350 ребрами, чтобы не надо было самому придумывать такой пример, чтобы измерить время

```
var graph = {

40: {41: 105.16330203209385, 49: 35.95854287280075, 91: 365.41610033805244},
41: {40: 105.16330203209385, 42: 52.89007014380016, 96: 284.90007530099},
42: {41: 52.89007014380016, 43: 49.86819899505683, 86: 357.4019834882249, 161: 291.8128348465009, 2551: 291.8207238893861, 8177: 125.51245953452907},
43: {42: 49.86819899505683, 44: 79.18079075547753, 69: 773.7300245357471, 137: 463.41237148188674, 168: 236.50394195087094, 184: 518.4807809544371, player: 424.2989071724448},
44: {43: 79.18079075547753, 45: 90.83360606053981, 90: 259.8407665207612, 95: 279.411144869276, 190: 246.32285632446946, 194: 224.5772017876507, 8177: 93.88798917266715},
45: {44: 90.83360606053981, 46: 40.2601818009928},
46: {45: 40.2601818009928, 47: 80.31837977090295, 160: 341.52947036128677, 167: 282.7221748698908},
47: {46: 80.31837977090295, 48: 45.378520844445866, 113: 84.10938294083888, 137: 513.6122449619479, 194: 309.30390726060676},
48: {47: 45.378520844445866, 49: 42.01982543140207},
49: {40: 35.95854287280075, 48: 42.01982543140207, 115: 80.73588919181459, 199: 382.4252940520127, 2551: 245.95308452576458, player: 356.16663709256125},
53: {54: 69.82905046610144},
54: {53: 69.82905046610144, 55: 36.89122723725341, 64: 672.2998601462713, db2: 445.06616939812926, db3: 1158.5442884850133},
55: {54: 36.89122723725341, 56: 25.28985792675144},
56: {55: 25.28985792675144},
60: {61: 35.416497801167246, 69: 33.91097748061123},
61: {60: 35.416497801167246, 79: 182.83357107127233},
64: {54: 672.2998601462713, db3: 486.7536481150631},
69: {43: 773.7300245357471, 60: 33.91097748061123, 134: 381.86594263303124, 138: 373.17392477929263, 168: 547.4030201239677, 184: 255.73717566383445, 8177: 729.9618210601787},
70: {79: 61.87457805450789},
73: {74: 27.53156245061905},
74: {73: 27.53156245061905, 75: 60.42930213144073, 214: 157.5379813237738},
75: {74: 60.42930213144073, 76: 23.04449141268447, 211: 130.4532561303535},
76: {75: 23.04449141268447, 77: 33.32706145836687, 145: 338.17803666210386},
77: {76: 33.32706145836687, 78: 44.436786980587094, 140: 369.8417462894574, 227: 370.64854634825195},
78: {77: 44.436786980587094, 79: 95.67987146765796},
79: {61: 182.83357107127233, 70: 61.87457805450789, 78: 95.67987146765796, 134: 458.3837359394246, 144: 164.08339248404633, 184: 285.80953218952124, 189: 378.9327568459244, 199: 522.8087714711911, 214: 247.458530942144, 219: 221.26599171060894, 222: 328.8566975982385},
80: {81: 31.99091133666505, 89: 47.37309491054031},
81: {80: 31.99091133666505, 82: 18.482125019131523, 92: 186.10076385620917},
82: {81: 18.482125019131523},
85: {86: 38.30910387902856, 160: 140.58712091180325, 8177: 277.7985746888594},
86: {42: 357.4019834882249, 85: 38.30910387902856, 87: 34.17590192185435, 98: 253.9010464199508},
87: {86: 34.17590192185435, 88: 31.717045454318647},
88: {87: 31.717045454318647, 89: 46.505807395662835},
89: {80: 47.37309491054031, 88: 46.505807395662835, 94: 11.77035161957156, 95: 38.52418784028625, 164: 238.16603610755064, 169: 246.42327116515582, 190: 548.4405778257062},
90: {44: 259.8407665207612, 91: 80.6040051899815, 99: 63.414851389705724},
91: {40: 365.41610033805244, 90: 80.6040051899815, 92: 129.31862590221718, 2551: 340.02623533449474, player: 350.04622145258276},
92: {81: 186.10076385620917, 91: 129.31862590221718, 93: 17.014794638367174},
93: {92: 17.014794638367174, 94: 107.81212095323181},
94: {89: 11.77035161957156, 93: 107.81212095323181, 95: 48.81440169056348, 169: 257.5421204372971, 190: 559.0816703975345},
95: {44: 279.411144869276, 89: 38.52418784028625, 94: 48.81440169056348, 96: 51.965228022387045, 8177: 188.1610655675721},
96: {41: 284.90007530099, 95: 51.965228022387045, 97: 42.493801157402245},
97: {96: 42.493801157402245, 98: 76.51874618264816},
98: {86: 253.9010464199508, 97: 76.51874618264816, 99: 50.256920854111094, 162: 254.03531208114921, 2551: 369.4527333309115, player: 430.38030020191263},
99: {90: 63.414851389705724, 98: 50.256920854111094, 168: 309.41194345952965, 184: 606.1752354860017, 194: 412.59609038621943, 8177: 128.39521986850684},
105: {106: 40.502652460422986, rb3: 596.3768944663615, rb4: 218.56615168137122},
106: {105: 40.502652460422986},
112: {113: 56.890826754690984},
113: {47: 84.10938294083888, 112: 56.890826754690984, 114: 44.971521845365736, 199: 377.72278954722674, 2551: 250.82487360351706},
114: {113: 44.971521845365736, 115: 30.39941919684934, player: 406.2603301787468},
115: {49: 80.73588919181459, 114: 30.39941919684934},
121: {122: 26.4764307012406, 180: 333.4919506962407, 197: 224.11574141326125},
122: {121: 26.4764307012406, 123: 85.09854045024798},
123: {122: 85.09854045024798, 124: 66.06615282686656, 188: 240.1895168095516, 222: 145.98976289724948},
124: {123: 66.06615282686656, 125: 68.9626658726196, 154: 285.63443323423286, 197: 81.28243262604742, 199: 120.03368992094568, 200: 521.1161335753012, 220: 132.9232424883914, 235: 502.7356682290173},
125: {124: 68.9626658726196, 126: 38.943242837290754},
126: {125: 38.943242837290754, 127: 33.163731118050336, 130: 488.36987469432336},
127: {126: 33.163731118050336, 128: 33.404198741679295, 189: 190.281661870841, 222: 179.82995490915707},
128: {127: 33.404198741679295},
130: {126: 488.36987469432336, 131: 39.32473302511219, 139: 61.03461545929612, 165: 81.30716116326501, 189: 331.8650824133968, 197: 301.74331187036734},
131: {130: 39.32473302511219, 132: 55.42370986351895},
132: {131: 55.42370986351895, 133: 79.69349323544078, 166: 67.3763049187362, 192: 318.54092414747043},
133: {132: 79.69349323544078, 134: 20.88052479596501},
134: {69: 381.86594263303124, 79: 458.3837359394246, 133: 20.88052479596501, 135: 35.59118973162082, 144: 610.3090410067813, 164: 180.61814056298095},
135: {134: 35.59118973162082, 136: 56.51867994261978, 185: 235.8916661215193},
136: {135: 56.51867994261978, 137: 63.301411556559216},
137: {43: 463.41237148188674, 47: 513.6122449619479, 136: 63.301411556559216, 138: 59.07343205194048, 180: 152.16660903789744, 193: 237.50078461204208},
138: {69: 373.17392477929263, 137: 59.07343205194048, 139: 36.593864364824086, 168: 174.26360890820277, 8177: 356.93660108485227},
139: {130: 61.03461545929612, 138: 36.593864364824086, 184: 163.52947726263545},
140: {77: 369.8417462894574, 141: 31.783831070674122, 149: 57.19080386036463, 157: 220.27163225083572},
141: {140: 31.783831070674122, 142: 43.52217897680467, 212: 355.7027373052974},
142: {141: 43.52217897680467, 143: 34.47915609273915, 153: 278.68421664307084, 219: 283.8179725289804},
143: {142: 34.47915609273915, 144: 63.30212258982895, 227: 121.85680795083613},
144: {79: 164.08339248404633, 134: 610.3090410067813, 143: 63.30212258982895, 145: 67.32562350561739, 185: 345.0079147553116, 223: 302.3593097992749},
145: {76: 338.17803666210386, 144: 67.32562350561739, 146: 40.002337310940405, 212: 308.5458007129418},
146: {145: 40.002337310940405, 147: 36.28002732885, 202: 114.02554819729143},
147: {146: 36.28002732885, 148: 38.80539895882165, 153: 272.4710445691966, 157: 236.17539343646496, 218: 360.2303518497902},
148: {147: 38.80539895882165, 149: 60.76422605278673},
149: {140: 57.19080386036463, 148: 60.76422605278673, 200: 219.7939434026094, 204: 201.55625431985254, 220: 185.04192904393753, 227: 77.76324371726739, 236: 258.1247404032064},
152: {153: 41.337936179115474, 227: 235.2074162235845},
153: {142: 278.68421664307084, 147: 272.4710445691966, 152: 41.337936179115474, 154: 77.56097298280768, 204: 368.14569546270917},
154: {124: 285.63443323423286, 153: 77.56097298280768, 155: 27.839694542272085, 209: 301.28170224107254, 221: 215.4335728798769, 235: 224.64469994242543},
155: {154: 27.839694542272085, 156: 18.982764068571615},
156: {155: 18.982764068571615, 157: 31.11961929802304},
157: {140: 220.27163225083572, 147: 236.17539343646496, 156: 31.11961929802304, 227: 228.18741588038438},
160: {46: 341.52947036128677, 85: 140.58712091180325, 161: 28.441599735803532, 169: 114.85066605391305, 8177: 140.33409704584713},
161: {42: 291.8128348465009, 160: 28.441599735803532, 162: 54.20012357975497},
162: {98: 254.03531208114921, 161: 54.20012357975497, 163: 41.3888146146421, 2551: 623.0399505311785},
163: {162: 41.3888146146421, 164: 40.25097587062904},
164: {89: 238.16603610755064, 134: 180.61814056298095, 163: 40.25097587062904, 165: 83.71679912082705},
165: {130: 81.30716116326501, 164: 83.71679912082705, 166: 47.13231992458931, 192: 301.51054155761403},
166: {132: 67.3763049187362, 165: 47.13231992458931, 167: 75.31708435243745},
167: {46: 282.7221748698908, 166: 75.31708435243745, 168: 22.06889237237542},
168: {43: 236.50394195087094, 69: 547.4030201239677, 99: 309.41194345952965, 138: 174.26360890820277, 167: 22.06889237237542, 169: 90.40807626927251, 8177: 182.71805709047803, player: 660.6320632458752},
169: {89: 246.42327116515582, 94: 257.5421204372971, 160: 114.85066605391305, 168: 90.40807626927251, 184: 387.60114332631235, 190: 304.43314188813645, 195: 246.22489560536593},
170: {},
171: {172: 39.00259005444423},
172: {171: 39.00259005444423, 173: 48.86649972594193},
173: {172: 48.86649972594193},
180: {121: 333.4919506962407, 137: 152.16660903789744, 181: 63.64776392942703, 189: 125.33020981473317, 197: 109.40475344201299},
181: {180: 63.64776392942703, 182: 24.718866358798138},
182: {181: 24.718866358798138, 183: 25.690918406222263},
183: {182: 25.690918406222263, 184: 38.751130184418095, 194: 197.83059642108458},
184: {43: 518.4807809544371, 69: 255.73717566383445, 79: 285.80953218952124, 99: 606.1752354860017, 139: 163.52947726263545, 169: 387.60114332631235, 183: 38.751130184418095, 185: 75.66100127301493, 8177: 478.2815951431},
185: {135: 235.8916661215193, 144: 345.0079147553116, 184: 75.66100127301493, 186: 49.6133887921204, 222: 218.04266558629692, 227: 305.5005550532781},
186: {185: 49.6133887921204, 187: 24.25053431206494},
187: {186: 24.25053431206494, 188: 42.8234357875276},
188: {123: 240.1895168095516, 187: 42.8234357875276, 189: 130.48152567212878},
189: {79: 378.9327568459244, 127: 190.281661870841, 130: 331.8650824133968, 180: 125.33020981473317, 188: 130.48152567212878, 195: 165.9262268374238, 199: 146.07459191521332, 219: 585.593015592556, 221: 105.54771303483847, 223: 128.16875394348722},
190: {44: 246.32285632446946, 89: 548.4405778257062, 94: 559.0816703975345, 169: 304.43314188813645, 191: 70.61802588549347, 199: 104.88079811045276, 8177: 337.2985237275377},
191: {190: 70.61802588549347, 192: 32.272029619118605},
192: {132: 318.54092414747043, 165: 301.51054155761403, 191: 32.272029619118605, 193: 41.35537604492597},
193: {137: 237.50078461204208, 192: 41.35537604492597, 194: 30.816119644011263},
194: {44: 224.5772017876507, 47: 309.30390726060676, 99: 412.59609038621943, 183: 197.83059642108458, 193: 30.816119644011263, 195: 31.40869971024647},
195: {169: 246.22489560536593, 189: 165.9262268374238, 194: 31.40869971024647, 196: 19.435562823007153, 8177: 318.945172309603},
196: {195: 19.435562823007153, 197: 107.1506698368598, 221: 251.92623057012156},
197: {121: 224.11574141326125, 124: 81.28243262604742, 130: 301.74331187036734, 180: 109.40475344201299, 196: 107.1506698368598, 198: 71.94959459518995},
198: {197: 71.94959459518995, 199: 53.21176924210634},
199: {49: 382.4252940520127, 79: 522.8087714711911, 113: 377.72278954722674, 124: 120.03368992094568, 189: 146.07459191521332, 190: 104.88079811045276, 198: 53.21176924210634, 222: 194.01671571159096},
200: {124: 521.1161335753012, 149: 219.7939434026094, 201: 51.59820366487804, 209: 57.03687052650553, 221: 446.669384670336},
201: {200: 51.59820366487804, 202: 82.8626939527005, 236: 90.37098960545049},
202: {146: 114.02554819729143, 201: 82.8626939527005, 203: 39.40638069110732, 218: 436.407907889379, 231: 137.42350047638314},
203: {202: 39.40638069110732, 204: 104.89480626042655},
204: {149: 201.55625431985254, 153: 368.14569546270917, 203: 104.89480626042655, 205: 63.30193294445094},
205: {204: 63.30193294445094},
209: {154: 301.28170224107254, 200: 57.03687052650553, 234: 116.05438254004737},
210: {211: 42.30165572597134, 219: 32.15172511880403},
211: {75: 130.4532561303535, 210: 42.30165572597134, 212: 60.0281194646555},
212: {141: 355.7027373052974, 145: 308.5458007129418, 211: 60.0281194646555, 213: 33.82825518940869, 227: 391.86061913738223},
213: {212: 33.82825518940869, 214: 42.54090537631494},
214: {74: 157.5379813237738, 79: 247.458530942144, 213: 42.54090537631494, 215: 49.888093699309934},
215: {214: 49.888093699309934, 216: 39.851515082343695},
216: {215: 39.851515082343695},
217: {218: 26.231546762251014},
218: {147: 360.2303518497902, 202: 436.407907889379, 217: 26.231546762251014, 219: 42.97667404536861},
219: {79: 221.26599171060894, 142: 283.8179725289804, 189: 585.593015592556, 210: 32.15172511880403, 218: 42.97667404536861, 222: 531.8522323663475, 227: 370.9990665742771},
220: {124: 132.9232424883914, 149: 185.04192904393753, 221: 57.38276622492863, 229: 24.18216024283879},
221: {154: 215.4335728798769, 189: 105.54771303483847, 196: 251.92623057012156, 200: 446.669384670336, 220: 57.38276622492863, 222: 81.23467948862621, 235: 428.52683452051633},
222: {79: 328.8566975982385, 123: 145.98976289724948, 127: 179.82995490915707, 185: 218.04266558629692, 199: 194.01671571159096, 219: 531.8522323663475, 221: 81.23467948862621, 223: 72.57090855008987},
223: {144: 302.3593097992749, 189: 128.16875394348722, 222: 72.57090855008987, 224: 61.0132077739784},
224: {223: 61.0132077739784, 225: 7.838317856740105},
225: {224: 7.838317856740105, 226: 30.448702787148285},
226: {225: 30.448702787148285, 227: 74.25253401337827},
227: {77: 370.64854634825195, 143: 121.85680795083613, 149: 77.76324371726739, 152: 235.2074162235845, 157: 228.18741588038438, 185: 305.5005550532781, 212: 391.86061913738223, 219: 370.9990665742771, 226: 74.25253401337827, 228: 59.677880235700854},
228: {227: 59.677880235700854, 229: 67.53231487179364},
229: {220: 24.18216024283879, 228: 67.53231487179364},
231: {202: 137.42350047638314, 232: 24.017731260242194},
232: {231: 24.017731260242194, 233: 14.363781980044742},
233: {232: 14.363781980044742, 234: 24.44948246300028},
234: {209: 116.05438254004737, 233: 24.44948246300028, 235: 39.324747502659484},
235: {124: 502.7356682290173, 154: 224.64469994242543, 221: 428.52683452051633, 234: 39.324747502659484, 236: 53.46540106587038},
236: {149: 258.1247404032064, 201: 90.37098960545049, 235: 53.46540106587038},
2551: {42: 291.8207238893861, 49: 245.95308452576458, 91: 340.02623533449474, 98: 369.4527333309115, 113: 250.82487360351706, 162: 623.0399505311785, 8177: 413.30376238306854},
8177: {42: 125.51245953452907, 44: 93.88798917266715, 69: 729.9618210601787, 85: 277.7985746888594, 95: 188.1610655675721, 99: 128.39521986850684, 138: 356.93660108485227, 160: 140.33409704584713, 168: 182.71805709047803, 184: 478.2815951431, 190: 337.2985237275377, 195: 318.945172309603, 2551: 413.30376238306854},
db2: {54: 445.06616939812926, lb1: 70.71067811865476},
db3: {54: 1158.5442884850133, 64: 486.7536481150631, rb3: 70.71067811865476},
lb1: {db2: 70.71067811865476, lb4: 814},
lb4: {lb1: 814, ub1: 70.71067811865476},
player: {43: 424.2989071724448, 49: 356.16663709256125, 91: 350.04622145258276, 98: 430.38030020191263, 114: 406.2603301787468, 168: 660.6320632458752},
rb3: {105: 596.3768944663615, db3: 70.71067811865476},
rb4: {105: 218.56615168137122, ub4: 70.71067811865476},
ub1: {lb4: 70.71067811865476, ub4: 1596},
ub4: {ub1: 1596, rb4: 70.71067811865476},
}
```

Если можно как-то оптимизировать те реализации, ссылки на которые я прикрепил выше, и от этих оптимизаций они станут быстро работать, буду тоже очень признателен!

Comment: классический репозиторий [JavaScript Algorithms and Data Structures](https://github.com/trekhleb/javascript-algorithms), [Dijkstra's Algorithm](https://github.com/trekhleb/javascript-algorithms/tree/master/src/algorithms/graph/dijkstra)

Comment: Спасибо! Случайно не знаете, там быстрый алгоритм приведён?

Comment: Первая задача - для Дейкстры. А вот вторая толком не поставлена. Из какой "одной точки в другую"? И если нужны миллисекунды, то почему используется такой язык?

Comment: Что по поводу второй задачи не понятно? Из одной точки на графе до другой точки на графе. Что касается языка. Мне такой алгоритм нужен для браузерного клиентского приложения. Логично использовать JavaScript. Или вы предлагает делать на одном языке, чтобы потом делать перекомпиляцию на тот же JavaScript?

Comment: Для Дейкстры задаётся **одна** исходная точка, и ищутся минимальные расстояния до всех других вершин. Если нужны произвольные исходные точки, то нужно делать n Дейкстр за кубическое время, или, что выгоднее, одного Флойда (за то же кубическое, но с меньшей константой)

Comment: Я разве не могу восстановить путь от исходной точки до нужной мне точки? Как его тогда восстанавливают в реализациях, которые я скинул выше?

Comment: От исходной до любой другой - можете. А от "неисходной" - нет.

Comment: я как раз это и имел в виду

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Реализация классического алгоритма Дейкстры, указанная nörbörnën, выглядит нормально.

Однако у Вас случай разрежённого (sparse) графа, т.к. количество ребёр сравнимо с числом вершин, а не с квадратом их количества.

Для этого случая есть эффективный алгоритм, [описанный здесь на C++](http://e-maxx.ru/algo/dijkstra_sparse), работающий за `O(E logV)`.

Я реализовывал подобный подход на Delphi для [решётчатого (grid) графа](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22355114/optimisation-of-a-dijkstra-shortest-path-search-in-delphi/22376696?) и для дорожного графа. Для 10^4 вершин ускорение было весьма значительное.